# Files in the Nice programming language

Tags: nice-language

Currently I'm working with the *Nice* programming language. But I don't find any information about working with files in this language.
If there'd be anybody who can help me with it, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The [language documentation](http://nice.sourceforge.net/language.html) (towards the bottom) provides an example for file access by interfacing with Java:

```
import java.io.*;

{ 
  String s; 
  ... 
  java.io.Writer w = new FileWriter(s); 
  w.write("Hello world"); 
  w.close(); 
}
```

It seems that currently, about all file interfaces are useable through the [Java interface](http://nice.sourceforge.net/manual.html#interfacingWithJava) only.